# Add two variables to one variable that contains an array

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to use "part1.length" in the function below by adding the variable "value" and "part" to one variable named "partvalue", which should contain "part1", so I can show the length of the array and use it in other functions. When I add '1' to 'value' then javascript should use the array 'part2'.

```
var part1 = {'Hallo','test'}
var part2 = {'Hallo2','test2'}


var value = 1;
var part = 'part'
var partValue = part + value;

var dosomething = function(){
if(anotherValue < partValue.length){..... // Javascript should work with "part1.length" there, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong. I didn't know what to search for on the internet, because I am very new here.
```

Comment: Check out the "associative arrays". It's doing exactly what you are trying to.

Comment: Check out *arrays*, period. `part[0]`, `part[1]` instead of `part1`, `part2`.